# SetWinEventHook doesn't work with specific process

Tags: c#, winapi, process, hook

UPD. I have the same situation in C++ win32 code.

C#:

WinAPI part:

```
    const uint EVENT_CONSOLE_CARET = 0x4001;
    const uint EVENT_CONSOLE_END_APPLICATION = 0x4007;

    delegate void WinEventDelegate(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint eventType, 
        IntPtr hwnd, int idObject, int idChild, uint dwEventThread, uint dwmsEventTime);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true))]
    static extern IntPtr SetWinEventHook(uint eventMin, uint eventMax,
        IntPtr hmodWinEventProc, WinEventDelegate lpfnWinEventProc,
        uint idProcess, uint idThread, uint dwFlags);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool UnhookWinEvent(IntPtr hWinEventHook);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);
```

Code:

```
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        process.Start();

        _winEventProc = new WinEventDelegate(WinEventProc);

        m_hhook = SetWinEventHook(EVENT_CONSOLE_CARET,
            EVENT_CONSOLE_END_APPLICATION, 
            IntPtr.Zero, 
            _winEventProc,
            (uint) process.Id,
            0,
            WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT); 
        lastError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
```

My program cannot catch events from process that I've created. If I change "(uint) process.Id" to "(uint) 0" it working good. I changed "(uint) process.Id" to specific process Id (watched it in task manager) and result was the same(bad). I even tried:

1) start cmd.exe (*)

2) start my program without creating new cmd.exe process

3) press any key at cmd.exe(*)

4) use GetWindowThreadProcessId in _winEventProc

5) re-run my program with pID that I get on 4 step

And it doesn't work. I don't know why but it working well only with processID 0.

p.s. sorry for my bad english

Comment: When that doesn't work, what is the value of `m_hhook`? And, if it's `0`, what is the return value of `GetLastError`?

Comment: In all cases (PID == `0`, `process.Id`, some particular value) `lastError` is `0` and `m_hhook` is "good" number (289800895, 24773505, 328759, 12845953 etc.) even in case when there is no process with that PID.

Comment: upd my question. I have the same situation in C++ Win32 project.